# Enable HTTP cached in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm using Nginx as a web server for my site. My goal is to enable caching on my site so my site can load faster. I've tried to add `proxy_cache one;`

---

**Nginx Config File**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name default;
    root /home/forge/web-app/public;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location ~* \.html$ {
      expires -1;
    }


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        #configure cache
        proxy_cache one; <----------------------------- Added HERE 
        proxy_cache_valid any 1m;
    }

    location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 168h;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/default-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

        #configure cache
        proxy_cache one;
        proxy_cache_valid any 1m;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

---

How do I properly enable HTTP cached in Nginx, and test my work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define this cache zone first using `proxy_cache_path`. Here's [the tutorial](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/).